# Remove the longest segments of a polygon using QGIS

Tags: polygon, editing, remove, segment

Is there an expression or tool that allows the user to remove the longest segments of a polygon? The end result would be two end segments (lines)

[image]

Comment: Are you sure the curve is not made of dozens of very small segments?

Comment: Good point - the longer segments of the polygon could be composed of many smaller segments, but this would need to be considered as well. I have looked into exploding the polygon and single part to multi part with no luck.

Comment: will it always only have 4 sides?

Comment: Pick a point at random start traversing, calculate bearing change with last 2 points, if bearing change is within threshold consider it to be one of the corners and start adding new points falling within same threshold of bearing change add to same linestring. If not create a new linestring. As a result you will get 4 linestrings. Calculate the length of linstring and separate out 2 longer sides of polygon vs 2 shorter. I can implement this using python and shapely if you want. Don't know about qgis.